# Slow parameter oscillations in coupled simple harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, adiabatic, coupled-oscillators

In a paper by [Turaev](https://pdfhost.io/v/8u1.uX87W_pre16pdf.pdf), he studies systems with a slow variation of parameters.
The following is on page two, right column:

He first discusses the one dimensional particle in a box, with ends at $x=-1$ and $x=a(\tau)$, where $a$ is periodic with period T in the slow time variable $\tau$. One assumes the validity of the adiabatic theorem.
At time interval $[\tau_1 ,\tau_2] \subset [0,T] $ there is a barrier at $x=0$.

Essentially, they argue that during the period of separation, the energy spectra split into the left-hand side and the right-hand side. Then, at the moment of reconnection, since the separation into the two groups of the energy spectra is physically meaningless, the energy levels essentially combine, and there is a new quantum number $k$ which labels the energy levels.

**My question:**

I wish to study the same problem, but with two simple harmonic oscillators being coupled and decoupled regularly. The energy spectra during the decoupling period are known, but I have an issue in modelling what happens when the harmonic oscillators couple.

I tried to read up on coupled quantum harmonic oscillators, but I couldn't find a clear way to figure out their energy spectra. Furthermore, I have no clue how to deal with the fact that the coupling strength will be turning on and off, and the effective spring constant is time-dependent.

Comment: Which paper? Which page?

Comment: sorry, I just linked it now

Comment: Permalink: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.93.050203

Comment: Thank you, I didn't link it to that in case it wasn't accessible, but I will change it.